# Stop refreshing from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment called `HomeFragment.java` which has another fragment inside that contains the cards as you can see in the gif. The problem is, whenever I go to another fragment and when I come back to my `HomeFragment.java` all the cards refresh and get new ones... How can I stop refreshing?

[image]

This is my `HomeFragment.java`

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private CardStackAdapter mAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View viewHome = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mPager = (ViewPager) viewHome.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerHome);
    mAdapter = new CardStackAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CardStackTransformer());
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    final TextView txtHomeTitulo = viewHome.findViewById(R.id.txtHomeTitulo);
    final TextView txtHomeDesc = viewHome.findViewById(R.id.txtHomeDesc);


    final ImageView imgCard1 = viewHome.findViewById(R.id.imgFotoPais);


    Typeface tpTitulos = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf");
    Typeface tpDesc = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/RobotoSlab-Light.ttf");


    txtHomeTitulo.setTypeface(tpTitulos);
    txtHomeDesc.setTypeface(tpDesc);

    return viewHome;

}

private class CardStackTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        if (position >= 0)
        {
            page.setScaleX(0.8f - 0.2f * position);
            page.setScaleY(0.8f);

            page.setTranslationX(- page.getWidth()*position);
            page.setTranslationY(30 * position);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

And this is my `MainActivityjava` where I have all the navigation toolbar fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // MODO IMERSIVO //
    immersiveMode(); // Método para colocar em modo imersivo

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
   bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.itemHome:
                    selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.itemExplore:
                    selectedFragment = new ExploreFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.itemCamera:
                    bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    selectedFragment = new CameraFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.itemProfile:
                    selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };


private void immersiveMode(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int UI_OPTIONS = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(UI_OPTIONS);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    immersiveMode();

    }
}
```

How can I stop the refresh?

Comment: you can achieve this by using `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Fragment every time a navigation item is selected.

Try having the fragments as class variables which are initialised in onCreate() in MainActivity. Then set selectedFragment using these initialised fragments, instead of creating new ones.

**EDIT**
Sample change:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav;

    HomeFragment mHomeFragment;
    ExploreFragment mExploreFragment;
    CameraFragment mCameraFragment;
    ProfileFragment mProfileFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // MODO IMERSIVO //
        immersiveMode(); // Método para colocar em modo imersivo

        mHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        mExploreFragment = new ExploreFragment();
        mCameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
        mProfileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, selectedFragment)
            .commit();
        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.itemHome:
                        selectedFragment = mHomeFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.itemExplore:
                        selectedFragment = mExploreFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.itemCamera:
                        bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        selectedFragment = mCameraFragment;
                        break;
                    case R.id.itemProfile:
                        selectedFragment = mProfileFragment;
                        break;
                }

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,selectedFragment)
                    .commit();
                return true;
            }
    };


    private void immersiveMode(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            int UI_OPTIONS = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | 
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | 
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
         getWindow().getDecorView()
             .setSystemUiVisibility(UI_OPTIONS);
    }
}
```

AFAIK, this will not cause performance issues. For more details, you can read up on a fragment's life cycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

Comment: Can you give me an example of that, please?
Would that effect in the performance of the app?

Comment: It works! The problem is the fragment with the cards inside my `HomeFragement.java` disappears... Here is the code of my `HomeFragment.java` where I call that other fragment:
https://pastebin.com/xFvQzM22

Comment: Could you elaborate in more detail?

Comment: Sure. In my `HomeFragment.java` which you can see in the gif I have a **View Pager** displaying another fragment inside called `CardStackFragment.java`. That fragment displays those cards that you see at the beginning, with a country image saying "Chipre". That fragment is called in `onCreateView` of `HomeFragment.java` so it only appears one time (when view of HomeFragment is created). I don't know if I was detailed enough

Comment: In HomeFragment.java, you never actually call beginTransaction() to load the new Fragment. So the code would be something like getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction.replace(containerID, mCardStackFragment).commit() in HomeFragment.java. If that creates an exception, put this line in the onResume() of HomeFragment.java.

Comment: Yeah, but I use this to call the fragment https://pastebin.com/M5944U6q

Comment: That just sets the adapter of the ViewPager. It does not set the Fragment.

Comment: Well, to be honest I copied this code from a youtube video. I don't know how the fragment does appear when I don't set it

Comment: Try the code in my comment in onResume of HomeFragment.java, with the necessary ID of the container and mCardStackFragment as new CardStackFragment().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174423/discussion-between-susmit-agrawal-and-andre-silva).